# BigQuery - format_date and year for iso 8601's week

Tags: google-bigquery

According to the bigquery documentation for [supported elements for format_date and format_datetime](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#supported-format-elements-for-datetime), I didn't find a way to represent the year + week in iso 8601 format; for instance "2017W01". The reason is that there are no operators for getting the year matching the `%V` week.

For instance the following query will return `"2008W01"` instead of `"2009W01"`

```
SELECT FORMAT_DATE('%YW%V',  DATE '2008-12-29')
```

With MySQL I would use `'%xW%v'` format that apparently has no equivalent with bigquery?

Comment: Downvoter, please add comments

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `SELECT FORMAT_DATE('%GW%V',  DATE '2008-12-29')` i.e. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#supported-format-elements-for-date _"%G The ISO 8601 year with century as a decimal number."_

Comment: @GrahamPolley thanks that was `%G`, didn't pay attention to this one. Feel free to upgrade as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `%G` as per the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#supported-format-elements-for-date): *"%G is the ISO 8601 year with century as a decimal number."*

`SELECT FORMAT_DATE('%GW%V', DATE '2008-12-29')`

Produces: `2009W01`